# DB Design - Suggestions

Tags: php, mysql

i really confused what to do and need your suggestions for my DB Design.

First of all,

[image]

As you see in the table, i have id,name,eventCategory,totalEvents and date . This table name is InitPlayer. InitPlayer is an eventAction and i have 3 more eventAction.

As you see in the table, eventCategory items always repetated because dates are changed.

First i though that i keep eventCategory as a table and retrieve items according to them.

What is your DB design suggestions acccording to this picture?
Thank you

Lastly,
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First i though that i keep eventCategory as a table and retrieve items according to them.

Hold that thought, and do it. Then create a `UserInitEventCategory` table, where you link `userInit.ID` to `eventCategory.ID`.

Comment: @MertMETİN yes, that looks promising.

Comment: what is the advantage of this i take numbers instead of varchar :S

Comment: _"what is the advantage of this"_ - pick up a decent book on database design that covers normalization.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should normalize the crap out of your database.

If you're continually reusing the same `eventCategory` items, you should make a little table, store their names in there, `eventCategories`, with `eventCategory_id` and `eventCategory_title` fields (or something similar), then just reference the ID of said `eventCategory` in the `initPlayer` table or create a table to references both `initPlayer` IDs and `eventCategories` IDs.

Normalizing and separating will help you to maintain order within your database and help keep you sane.  You'll have a little more work with your queries, but it's worth it if you want to scale, or say, change the name of a specific eventCategory.